# QuickOSM does not want to run preset

Tags: quickosm

I was making a map for a specific area, and while putting all OSM objects linked to buIldings or roads,everytime I click the run query this pop ups :
2024-01-23T19:04:32 CRITICAL Error in the QGIS log window, then the QuickOSM panel, copy/paste it and please report it, if you know how to copy/paste QGIS logs. Please check pinned tickets first.

2024-01-23T19:43:51     CRITICAL    Error: Algorithm qgis:checkvalidity not found

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I was making a map for a specific area, and while putting all OSM objects linked to buIldings or roads,everytime I click the run query this pop ups : 2024-01-23T19:04:32     CRITICAL    Error in the QGIS log window, then the QuickOSM panel, copy/paste it and please report it, if you know how to copy/paste QGIS logs. Please check pinned tickets first.

Comment: it also says: 2024-01-23T19:14:56     WARNING    Could not write to C:/Users/63926/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/QuickOSM/resources/i18n/